# Closing audio line causes 2 sec lag when only 1 second of audio data remains

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, lag, javasound

I've been trying to implement a way to play audio in my Java application using java's sound API. I've got a few problems here and there, but the most annoying one right now is that closing a channel `clip.close()` when there is less than one second remaining of audio lags my application for 2 seconds.

I dug around and figured out that, for some reason, when the line is trying to terminate its thread with the command `thread.join(2000)`, the thread is still alive and it causes it to wait for that whole 2 second to end.

The thread just so happens to stay alive only if there is less than 1 second of audio left. At any other time, when I try to stop the audio, no problems occur.

Here's the code that's being called:

```java
clip.close();
```

Which goes to

```java
/**
* This should also stop the line.  The closed line should not be running or active.
* After we close the line, we reset the format and buffer size to the defaults.
*/
@Override
public final void close() {
    //$$fb 2001-10-09: Bug #4517739: avoiding deadlock by synchronizing to mixer !
    synchronized (mixer) {
        if (isOpen()) {
            // stop
            stop();

            // set the open state to false and send events
            setOpen(false);

            // close resources for this line
            implClose();
            //... more code
        }
    }
}
```

`implClose` then goes to

```java
@Override
void implClose() {
    // dispose of thread
    Thread oldThread = thread;
    thread = null;
    doIO = false;
    if (oldThread != null) {
        // wake up the thread if it's in wait()
        synchronized(lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
        // wait for the thread to terminate itself,
        // but max. 2 seconds. Must not be synchronized!
        try {
            oldThread.join(2000); //This is where the problem occurs. The thread is still alive and the application is forced to wait 2 seconds.
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
    }
}
```

Here is the join method

```java
public final synchronized void join(final long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    if (millis > 0) {
        if (isAlive()) {
            final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            long delay = millis;
            do {
                wait(delay);
            } while (isAlive() && (delay = millis -
                    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startTime)) > 0);
        }
    } else if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure it out for the last 4 hours, but with an internet connection that is down 80% of the time and inadequate java knowledge, I haven't been able to yet.

Thank you for your time!

**Edit:**

Here is how the clip is instantiated and closed:

I first get a clip from a list of lines offered by the mixer:

```
//This is done with the main thread
for (Line.Info lineInfo : linesInfo) {
        if (lineInfo.getLineClass().isAssignableFrom(Clip.class)) {
            try {
                line =  AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
                clip = (Clip) line;
                audioPlayback.setClip(clip);//This is a custom class that holds the clip
            }
            catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is ran from the custom class when I press on a button to start the clip:

```
//Main thread is used here too
try {
    //Code to get format, data and data length
                
    clip.open(format, data, 0, length);
}
catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

And finally, to close the clip:

```
//Main thread executes this as well
clip.close();
```

Everything is done using the initial thread. I even removed all other thread instantiations from my code to make sure no other threads could cause the issue, but to no avail.

**Edit 2:**[image]

The red thread hangs for two seconds when stop is pressed(when there is less than a second of audio left).

Comment: I did figure out a way to unfreeze the application, although it is not pretty. I create a new thread and send it to die by closing the audio clip. This prevents me from accessing the clip for 2 seconds, but I'm at least not stuck waiting for the main thread.

Comment: Why do you need to wait at all? Can you not use `Clip.addLineListener` to add a listener which watches for `LineEvent.Type.STOP`  events and triggers whatever you want to do next there. If this is a GUI program you should avoid any sort of wait.

Comment: Could you indicate whether the code you show being called by `clip.close()` is either system code or code that you have written? I'm guessing the former but am not sure. On my system, I'm only seeing the interface for `Line` when I drill down, not the implementation. AFAIK, `line.close()` should send a request to the line to release resources, and this should happen behind the scenes (executing in a fire-and-forget manner, returning immediately). There are no guarantees on how long it will take. Can you indicate how the lag manifests? It shouldn't cause a control flow block.

Comment: @greg-449
The code shown in my question is unfortunately not mine. I have no power over it. I simply ran the debugger and followed it to these methods.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner It is unfortunately not my code. All that can be seen here is code that I found through the java debugger. 
"Can you indicate how the lag manifests?" As soon as I call close, the API tries to kill the thread that was used to run the audio clip and it freezes the main thread in the process (because of the join method). This causes my entire application to freeze for the whole 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, have verified the debug path. I have the same. OK. Given the warning about synchronization in `implClose`, I wonder if there is something that you have done with the `Clip` or a thread containing the `Clip` that pertains to synchronization. Normally, a `Clip` creates a daemon thread that holds the play back code. Can you show how you configured the Clip and the code that plays it? Perhaps it is in a wrapper that is synchronized?

Comment: Recapping: (1) `Clip.close()` method blocking is not normal. (2) The debug code you show is all "normal". THEREFORE: if the clip is in a container, is being managed, that is next likely cause of the issue. So can you show that code? You say the problem behavior only occurs when there is less that one second left to play. So in the case where there is more than one second left to play, playback stops immediately and the system doesn't hang? Or are you doing something to allow the sound to play to completion? This kind of suggests something going on with a container code for the clip.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Sure thing, I'll update the post with how I instantiate the clip. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @PhilFreihofner And to answer your last question: 
"So in the case where there is more than one second left to play, playback stops immediately and the system doesn't hang?(1) Or are you doing something to allow the sound to play to completion?(2)"

1. Exactly, no hanging as long as I have more than one second of audio left to play.
2.As soon as I click stop, my code stops the audio using clip.close(), then hangs at the "join" method shown above.

Comment: When there is more than a second, does the audio stop immediately on close or does it play out a second or two then stop?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner It stops immediately. It hangs as soon as it reaches the implClose(); method. Before that, it manages to run the stop() and setOpen(False) method without any delay. I forgot to save my edit, I've got new code to show.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking for more code. Can you show the custom class that holds the clip? You refer to it with the method `audioPlayback.setClip(clip)`. Is synchronization ever used with this class? Does this class exist on its own thread? Meanwhile, I'll try again to create a simple case that recreates the problem.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Of course! I tried not to show too much of it to keep it more concise, but that's no problem. It is not on its own thread and synchronization is not used within it. https://github.com/LouisBouch/SpectrumAnalyzer/blob/master/SpectrumAnalyzer/src/soundProcessing/AudioPlayback.java

Comment: @PhilFreihofner This problem might be windows exclusive. I think I remember you saying that you were on Linux. If you want to save some time trying to recreate the issue, I can send you the github link to the project. If you've got no problem, I'll know that this issue is exclusive to my operating system.

And thank you so much for your time, it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following is is intended to be a more minimal case that demonstrates the problem. I *am* able to recreate the problem with this code.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ClipCloseTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        
            public void run()
            {   
                ClipTestFrame frame = new ClipTestFrame();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }   
}

class ClipTestFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Clip clip;
    private JButton btnPlay, btnClose, btnReopen;
    private long timeStamp;
    
    public ClipTestFrame(){
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        btnPlay = new JButton("Play clip");
        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clip.start();
                btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                btnClose.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        btnClose = new JButton("Close Clip");
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //clip.stop();  // this line make no difference
                clip.close();
                timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Elapsed time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp0));
                btnClose.setEnabled(false);
                btnReopen.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        
        btnReopen = new JButton("Reopen Clip");
        btnReopen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openClip();
                btnReopen.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        
        openClip();
        btnClose.setEnabled(false);
        btnReopen.setEnabled(false);
        
        panel.add(btnPlay);
        panel.add(btnClose);
        panel.add(btnReopen);
        add(panel);
    }
    
    private void openClip() {
        // Set up the AudioCue
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("sineticking3secs.wav");
        try {
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(ais);
            System.out.println("clip.open executed");
            
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The resource **sineticking3secs.wav**, was made using *Audacity*. Format: 16-bit, 44100 fps, stereo, little-endian. It was made by appending 500 millisecond length sine tones using the *Generate* tool, at 220, 330, 220, 330, 440, 660 Hz. The segments make it easier to tell how close to the end we are when we close the clip. Can be downloaded from http://adonax.com/audio/sineticking3secs.wav

For both Java 11 and Java 18 running on Windows 11, the elapsed time listed on the console when the *Close Clip* button is pressed confirms that there is a 2-second pause when the button calls the `clip.close()` method, but only when the `Clip` has less than one second's worth of data left to play.

I tried looking at bug reports on Clip, but I can't figure out how to find the documentation on the details. There are a couple that mention the timing of closing in the title, for example https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8207506. How does one navigate to the details? [EDIT: I tried a search on the bug ID and found this: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8207210, so it isn't the same bug. I will try posting a bug report later in the day if I get a chance.]

I experimented with using a `SourceDataLine` instead of a `Clip`. There was no problem closing the `SourceDataLine`.

I wrote a library called [AudioCue-maven](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue-maven) that has a Clip "improvement". *AudioCue* uses `SourceDataLine` for output and causes no pauses when closing. It's available via maven.org, (groupid is com.adonax, artifactID is audiocue).

If you decide to try it, the code for instantiating is as follows:

```
    private void makeAudioCue() {
        // Set up the AudioCue
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("sineticking3secs.wav");
        try {
            clip = AudioCue.makeStereoCue(url, 1);
            clip.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Closing will close the associated `SourceDataLine` but won't remove the AudioCue's internal PCM array from memory. You'll have to set the variable to null for that. But if you simply reopen the AudioCue after closing it, it will play from the point where it was closed, so one has to reposition it back to the start `clip.setFramePosition(0)`.

Comment: "Why is AudioPlayback a Runnable? Clips create their own threads internally for playback. The run() method you have doesn't seem to be serving a purpose that can't be covered by simpler commands."

This was because of the "fix" I implemented. Instead of using the main thread to close the clip, I create a new thread to make sure the main one doesn't freeze, thus stopping everything else.

I tried to remove any intermediary method and simply close the clip with clip.close(). This unfortunately did not work.

I will try to implement your code and see whether it freezes or not. 

Thank you

Comment: Well, it looks like this problem is exclusive to the operative system I use, or the java version or something. Even with your code, the problem occurs. Closing with one second left freezes the entire app for 2 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for everything you did. I'd give you a rep, but I can't even cast a vote with my account.

Comment: I'm using the latest java OracleJDK, 18.0.2.1 with the JavaSE-16 library on a windows 10 MSI laptop. I have a Windows update to do. Unless I come back in 5 minutes to say that the issue is fixed, it means that the update has changed nothing.

I, unfortunately, don't have access to another laptop to test it on.

Comment: I deleted comments and rewrote my answer. I am now able to replicate the problem. I previously overlooked the effect because of looking at the console-ticking, not at the response after clicking the Close Clip button and delay enabling the Reopen Button. The added console messaging shows the effect.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was away for the weekend. I tried flushing, stopping and draining the clip before closing it, to no avail. How did you manage to do it? The only way I can prevent the issue is by stopping it manually and then closing it, but I assume this only works because of the added delay between the two functions.

Comment: My mistake. Stopping before closing the Clip doesn't help. IDK what I did to fool myself into thinking it helped. Meanwhile, I trimmed down the minimal example to just the three buttons: play, close and reopen.

Comment: Although it does seem to happen less often when stopping, draining or flushing, nothing really works. This relative success might help us understand what is happening behind the scene.